# How do I make a custom style the default style for an element?

Tags: plugins, ckeditor5, craftcms

I am creating a CraftCMS site and am using the new CkEditor plugin that Pixel and Tonic recommends. I have created a few custom styles for heading3, p, and li tags. I would like to make these custom styles the default styles for these elements so the user has to do less work.

I have looked at the documentation as well as tried to find any resources online but I haven't been able to find anything helpful. I'm hoping anyone who knows whether it is possible could help me out.